# Filtering away javascript objects into an array when using fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, promise

I have a react application, where I use the axios library, to get some values, and set them into an array of javascript objects in my state

```
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/zoo/api/animals')
.then(res => this.setState({animals: res.data}))
}
```

Now I want to check if the objects, contains an `Owner` object, inside it, and filter out does that does,

First, I tried making a const, and then using the filter, to check if they contain the objects, and then set the state, but I can't save my values in a local variable

```
  componentDidMount(){
const animals= [];
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/zoo/api/animals')
.then(res => animals=res.data)
console.log(animals) // logs empty array
console.log('mounted') 
  }
```

how can I make it so, that I can only get the animals that do NOT, have an owner object inside it?

[image: Example with owner]

Comment: `animals` is empty because `axios.get` is asynchronous. You need to perform the filter inside a `then` callback

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: In any case, that doesn't answer your original question - have you tried to filter the results?

Comment: You're right @chazsolo but a great answer was provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `animal` array is empty in your second example because `axios.get` is asynchronous, what is in your `then` will be executed once the data is fetch, but the function will keep on going in the meantime.

To filter out your array, simply use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) right after fetching your data :

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/zoo/api/animals')
        .then(res => this.setState({animals: res.data.filter(animal => !animal.owner)}))
}
```

This function will filter out every animal object that does not have an `owner` property.

Working example :

```js
const animals = [
 {
  name: 'Simba',
  owner: {
   some: 'stuff'
  }
 },
 {
  name: 1
 }, ,
 {
  name: 2
 }, ,
 {
  name: 3,
  owner: {
   some: 'stuff'
  }
 },
 {
  name: 'Bambi'
  //status: 'dead'
 }
]

console.log(animals.filter(animal => animal.owner))
```

EDIT: the answer was changed so that it only filters animals, that does not have an owner

Comment: I wanted to make it so, that i only have animals that does not have an owner though

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstodd the question, simply put an exclamation point before the condition : `filter(animal => !animal.owner)`. That should do it